# Javascript if statement not working ecommerce

Tags: javascript, html

The site I'm working on requires that if the total amount is less than 399 then a delivery fee of 100 is to be charged. However I put:

```
 //<![CDATA[  
simpleCart({    
  if(total<399){shippingFlatRate: 100;}      
}); 
//]]>
```

the main function has the total amount and that works and flat rate is set on, but when I use this if statement it stays on 0 and doesn't become 100.

Comment: Have you checked `console` for any errors? `{ if(total<399){shippingFlatRate: 100;} }` is invalid line.

Comment: Are you trying to write a function ? Syntax seems incorrect to me.

Comment: can you show the content of `simpleCart`

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to set the property of an object then your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
shippingFlatRate: total < 399 ? 100 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the wrong coded. If you have an object and needs to define a variable with a conditional, you can make this:

```
simpleCart({   

   shippingFlatRate: function() {
      if(total<399){
        return 100; //it takes 100 of value
      } else {
        return 0; // it takes 0 of value
      }
   }

});
```